# How to cancel a packet scheduled for time-based transmission after it's enqueued?

Tags: linux, ethernet, timestamps, socket, real-time

I have a time-sensitive networking application I am writing that involves receiving individual Ethernet frames, and then sending the data onward in another Ethernet frame after a precise 1 second delay (with a bit of processing in the middle ofc).

One particular sticking point, however, is that I also need the ability to *cancel* sending a packet onward, if another different type of message is received during that delay interval.

In order to get the precise 1 second delay, I'm using the kernel's [socket timestamp functionality](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/timestamping.html) in conjunction with [time-based packet transmission](https://lwn.net/Articles/748879/). The combination of these two features makes it possible to produce a predictable and reasonably precise delay, while still keeping the application in userland and not requiring the whole system run on a real-time process scheduler.

In specific, I'm creating the socket with `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, TEST_ETHERTYPE)` (the real application will be dealing with IPv4, but for now I'm using another ethertype for testing), and then setting the `SO_TIMESTAMPNS` and `SO_TXTIME` socket options to both generate packet arrival timestamps and allow specifying transmit times.

Then, in the main loop, the application would use the `recvmsg` api to get back a `SCM_TIMESTAMPNS` control message along with the received packet data, process the packet into the packet to send, and then use the `sendmsg` api to enqueue it for transmission with a `SCM_TXTIME` control message containing a timestamp exactly one second after the initial received timestamp.

However, there doesn't seem to be any way to actually "take back" a packet after it's been enqueued -- even when using time-based transmission where a packet might be resident in the queue for some significant period.

I understand that I can implement my own packet queue within my application that, and then only schedule packets with the kernel once they're very close to coming due; this might even be the correct move anyway to avoid stressing the kernel's queue. Regardless of how it's accomplished, there's always going to be some nonzero interval near the end of the delay where it won't be possible to guarantee that a packet gets cancelled before it's transmitted.

But if it's *only* possible to cancel packet from my application's own software queue, then the worst-case cancellation window is necessarily pessimized much further by the need to account for more scheduling inconsistency when ensuring the packet gets enqueued before the deadline. And it's also just a lot more complexity in general to have to manage multiple threads for different ends of this software queue.

In short: Is there any way of canceling a packet that's scheduled for time-based transmission after it has already been enqueued with the kernel?